# Google App Engine: post a group of entities at one time

Tags: python, google-app-engine, templates

I am trying to collect a group of data using a form, but I don't know how to get data from the form using POST. Thanks in advance. The program:

main.py

```
    from google.appengine.ext import db
    import webapp2
    import common

    class Company(db.Model):
        name: db.StringProperty()
        image: db.BlobProperty()
        url: db.URLProperty()

    class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
        def get(self):
            common.render(self, 'main.html', {'range': range(10)})

        def post(self):
            # How to do the following?
            for i in range(10):
                company = Company()
                company.name = self.request.get("name")
                company.image = self.request.get("image")
                company.url = self.request.get("url")
                company.put()            

    app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)], debug=True)
```

main.html

```
    <form action="/"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table>
    <tr><th></th><th>Company</th><th>Image</th><th>URL</th></tr>
    {% for i in range %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ forloop.counter }}: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" /></td>
        <td><input type="file" name="image" id="image" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="url" id="url" /></td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
    <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

-- Tang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.getall(key)` should do it for you.

```
# All values for a key: ['a', 'b']
check_values = request.POST.getall('check')
```

[Webapp2 Request Data](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/request.html)